# Self Descriptive numbers program in java for a newbie

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to make a program that searches through 4-digit numbers and tries to identify the two self descriptive numbers (a number that has the first digit equal to the number of zeroes in the whole number and the next digit equal the number of ones in the whole number and so on), I have written a do-loop:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;     

public class Numbers
{
int integers = 0;
      do
        {
            integer++;
        }
        while (integer <= 3210);
}
```

which would go through all 4 digit numbers that could possibly contain the type of output I'm looking for.

I want to find a way to determine if "integer" is a self descriptive number.

(I only started programming recently so I'm not very good)

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having?

Comment: You would cast `integer` as String and then use `String.charAt(0)` to test the first digit, `charAt(1)` to test the 2nd digit, and so on.

Comment: @AaronGillion It's usually better to use `%10` to get the units digit and integer division to get any other digit to become the units digit.

Comment: @Teepeemm I figured there was a math way to do it. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (integer <= 3210) {
        char firstDigit = (integer.toString()).charAt(0);
        char secondDigit = '0';
        char thirdDigit = '0';
        char fourthDigit = '0';
        if ((integer.toString().length()) > 1) {
            secondDigit = (integer.toString()).charAt(1);
            if ((integer.toString().length()) > 2) {
                thirdDigit = (integer.toString()).charAt(2);
                if ((integer.toString().length()) > 3) {
                    fourthDigit = (integer.toString()).charAt(3);
                }
            }
        }
        int numOfZeroes = 0;
        int numberOfOnes = 0;
        int numberOfTwos = 0;
        int numberOfThrees = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < (integer.toString()).length()) {
            if ((integer.toString()).charAt(i) == '0') {
                numOfZeroes++;
            } else if ((integer.toString()).charAt(i) == '1') {
                numberOfOnes++;
            } else if ((integer.toString()).charAt(i) == '2') {
                numberOfTwos++;
            } else if ((integer.toString()).charAt(i) == '3') {
                numberOfThrees++;
                i++;
            }
            if (firstDigit == numOfZeroes + '0' && secondDigit == numberOfOnes + '0'
                    && thirdDigit == numberOfTwos + '0' && fourthDigit == numberOfThrees + '0') {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
            integer++;
        }
    }
```

This will work the way you want and only for this particular range of numbers. However, there is no output from this, but I tested this with just first two conditions that you mentioned and worked fine.

I think there would be a better way to do this. This is kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better solution using Java 8 stream but here is a more traditional approach.

```
String s = Integer.toString(integer);
        boolean isDescriptive = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length() && isDescriptive) {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i) + "");
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (i == Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(j) + "")) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count != temp) {
                isDescriptive = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
```